# Problem print unicode and arabic character

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, unicode

I have stored in my database some string Unicode and Arabic
in the correct form
this is the screen of query select

https://i.ibb.co/JyCh9TJ/Screen-Shot-2019-09-11-at-8-45-37-PM.png

when I have used on my code
echo $data;

I have this result
https://i.ibb.co/28CH9n3/Screen-Shot-2019-09-11-at-8-49-28-PM.png

can you help me show the same data, please

Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much that work

Comment: I love you my brothers have saved me from a big problem

Comment: Next time could you accept the duplicate instead of posting thanks in the comments, please? It means the same to us and helps others.

Comment: The question marks happen when `INSERTing`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

To show UTF-8 content in your HTML, you need to ensure your text is actually in UTF-8 at three stages:

**1- The database** (which is already good in your case)

**2- The PHP query result:**

For this, add `charset=UTF8;` to your database connection string, e.g.:

```
...Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;charset=UTF8;
```

**3- The HTML output:**

For this, add this`meta` tag to your HTML document's head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4; host=" . $host
                . "; dbname=" . $db,
                $user, $pass);